# Concise syntax for function composition in Scala?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, function-composition

I'm learning Scala and ran across the following task - if string is blank then return null, otherwise uppercase it.

There are two functions in Apache Commons that composed together solves the problem. In Haskell I'd just write:

```
upperCaseOrNull = StringUtils.stripToNull . StringUtils.upperCase
```

However I can't find a way to do an easy and clean function composition in Scala. the shortest way I found is as follows:

```
def upperCaseOrNull (string:String) = StringUtils.stripToNull (StringUtils.upperCase(string))
def upperCaseOrNull = StringUtils.stripToNull _ compose StringUtils.upperCase _
```

Does Scala offer a more concise syntax, possibly without all those underscores?

Comment: def upperCaseOrNull (string:String) =  if (string == "") null else string.toUpperCase

Answer (score 2):

Haskell is a master of extreme compactness for a few things it really cares about.  So it's pretty much impossible to beat.  If you are doing so much function composition that the overhead really gets in your way (personally, I'd be a lot more troubled by repeating `StringUtils.`!), you can do something like

```
implicit class JoinFunctionsCompactly[B,C](g: B => C) {
  def o[A](f: A => B) = g compose f
}
```

so now you only have four extra characters (`_` twice) over Haskell.

Comment: i don't agree that it's a haskell feature. composing functions is a fundamental feature of all functional languages. in racket: `(define trim-upercase (compose string-trim string-upcase))`. if we have to pass parameter or its substitute (underscore) then it seems like an unnecessary function wrapping: http://www.amara.org/pl/videos/I7DUcht5Am5L/info/5-unnecessary-function-wrapping/

Comment: @piotrek - If you define your functions as functions (i.e. `val upperCase = (s: String) => ...`) then there's no need for `_`.  Also, who cares about a few underscores if overall it's approximately as compact?  Racket is no more compact than Scala here.  Racket's overhead is `(define  (compose ))`, while Scala's is `def = _ compose  _`.  If you just mean "I don't like the look of underscores", define a compose method and `compose(g,f)`.

Comment: To compose `g.h` use `JoinFunctionsCompactly(g).o(h)` and to compose `f.g.h`: `JoinFunctionsCompactly(f).o(JoinFunctionsCompactly(g).o(h))`

Comment: @AJarofClay - You could, but that's not the point of the code.  You can just use `g o h` or `f o g o h`.

Comment: @RexKerr you're right, although it should be `g _ o h` or `f _ o g o h`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't claim a task be simple if `null`'s are involved. Why would you need `null` if `None` in Scala would do? I think that due to `null` being returned the function is not very compose-friendly.

Once you transform `StringUtils.stripToNull` to return `None` for `null` and `Some` otherwise, you could then use [scala.Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option).map and execute it with `_.toUpperCase` - see the scaladoc for [scala.Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) where this particular example is discussed.

One might also suggest something as follows:

```
scala> def upperCaseOrNone = (s: String) => Option(s).fold(s) { _.toUpperCase }
upperCaseOrNone: String => String
```

Comment: why would i need `null` if `None` is available? because in hql query i can't use `None`

Comment: furthermore i believe that `null` is irrelevant here. i want to compose two existing functions, not wrapping them in `Option` or defining a new lambda

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make composition slightly more compact:

**Using `andThen`**

To get it down to a single underscore (even with more than two functions composed):

```
def upperCaseOrNull = StringUtils.upperCase _ andThen StringUtils.stripToNull
```

More general case with three functions:

```
def fgh  = h _ andThen g andThen f
```

**Using a helper function**

If `f`, `g` and `h` are functions taking one `String` parameter and returning a `String`:

```
def fgh = composeMany[String](f, g, h)
```

Where the `composeMany` function looks like this:

```
def composeManyHelper[T](composed: T => T, funcs: Seq[T => T]): T => T = {
  if (funcs.isEmpty) {
    composed
  } else {
    composeManyHelper[T](funcs.head compose composed, funcs.tail)
  }
}

// Take zero or more functions that take a param of type T and return a value of type T,
// and return a function that is the composition of all the functions
def composeMany[T](funcs: (T => T)*): T => T = {
  composeManyHelper[T](identity[T], funcs.reverse)
}
```