# Neat function composition in Scala

Tags: scala, function-composition

A common way to compose a function

```
def f(i: Int) = i + 1
```

includes

```
f(f(1))
```

Yet, how to enable or define a neater syntax such as

```
f f 1
```

A similar enquiry is formulated in [Concise syntax for function composition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22410045/3189923) though it proves unclear how this neat syntax may be reached.

**Update** If possible, how could this be achieved, at least in a similar (neat) fashion ?

Comment: Are you asking whether this is possible, or have you seen this before?

Comment: If you want, you could do this:

val ff = f _ andThen f _; ff(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible. No matter what you do, `g f 1` will always be parsed as `g.f(1)`, which means a member `f` will be lookup up among `g`'s members, and never in the (local) scope.